# Cancelling a modal view crashes the app -- Seeking Solution

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, modalviewcontroller

My app is crashing when I am trying to dismiss a modal view using:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

This is the flow of the application:

ViewController (My app landing screen) --> Push couple of view controllers --> Show the modal view.

Now, is my intention of canceling the modal view from the same modal controller (self) is correct or should I cancel it from somewhere else.

I had tried passing the object of the last conroller class in the stack to my modal controller and tried following code but it still crashes:

```
[self.lastStackObj dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Appreciate if someone can guide!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're releasing an already released object in the dealloc.
try commenting all the release statements in the dealloc & then try running, hopefully it wont crash. 
You can fix it by finding the variable & releasing it only once.

There maybe other problems causing this too. But this is the first thing i'd look for.